# Combine Window Functions First and Last

Tags: sql, pyspark

Is there an easier way to use first and last value window functions than to derive first and last values from CTEs/Tables/Subquery and then join on key?

Toy example below.  In reality my data set is large and in hadoop with many more records and fields.

For each customer, I want to see what the first item they bought (indicated by purchase_number increments) as well as the last item_origin.

"source_table" in sample query below.

| customer_id | purchase_number | item | item_origin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 1 | ball | Ohio |
| 0001 | 2 | paper | Texas |
| 0001 | 3 | pen | Kansas |
| 0002 | 1 | pen | Kansas |
| 0003 | 1 | paper | Texas |
| 0004 | 2 | frisbee | Florida |

If this was the complete table, the result should be:

| customer_id | first_item | last_item_origin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | ball | Kansas |
| 0002 | pen | Kansas |
| 0003 | paper | Florida |

Here's how I'm currently implementing this, but it seems kind of contrived.

```
WITH min_max AS (
SELECT 
    customer_id,
    MIN(purchase_number) AS min_row, 
    MAX(purchase_number) AS max_row 
FROM 
    source_table
GROUP BY 
    customer_id

),
min_ AS (
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    source_table a
    JOIN min_max b
        ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
        AND a.purchase_number = b.min_row
),
max_ AS (
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    source_table a
    JOIN min_max b
        ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
        AND a.purchase_number = b.max_row
)

SELECT
    a.customer_id,
    a.item,
    b.item_origin
FROM
    min_ a
    JOIN max_ b
        ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation and window functions:

```
select customer_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then item end) as first_item,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then item_origin end) as last_item_origin
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_number) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_number desc) as seqnum_desc
      from source_table s
     ) s
group by customer_id;
```